# How can I measure the power output of RF Power amplifier

Tags: amplifier

I have a power amp (50 Ohm) that is connected to a load of Z=55e(-0.77i), by standard coaxial cable with 50 ohm BNC connector.  The wiring is short, less than 1 metre.

The voltage reading from the RF PowerAmp is 40.1 V Amplitude (or 80.2 Vpp) with the load Z. How can I calculate the power output?

The reading I have is 10 W (from Power Amplifier integrated circuit) but I cannot calculate to anywhere close to that number

Comment: Yes... 40 V will be more like 25-35 W, depending on the length of the cable to that 55 Ohm load. Was the 40 V measured with the load connected? What frequency are you measuring at? With what instrument did you measure the voltage? RMS or peak or peak-to-peak?

Comment: so, I need to take into account the length of the cable?

Comment: this may help http://www.ab4oj.com/test/pwrmeas.html - Absolute RF Power Measurement using Simple Techniques

Comment: I don't recognize the notation you are using for complex impedance. But if it is 40V peak, then RMS is 40/sqrt(2) = 28.3 VRMS. So the power delivered to the load (if that is the actual output Voltage) would be V^2 / Z. If the magnitude is 55, then I come up with 14.5 Watts, but that wouldn't be the real power, since you seem to have an imaginary component in your impedance.

Comment: it's -0.77 rad on phasor diagram. So the wattage displayed on the RF Power Amp is wrong?

Comment: @NhânLê, If the phase angle is 0.77 radians, then the power factor is cos(0.77) = 0.72. So the real power is 0.72 * 14.5, which is 10W. I think your power amp is correct. I think it is displaying the real power.

Comment: I think that would be the answer. Would you be kind enough to elaborate the steps?